# about $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

When 
$$
A =\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix},\quad  a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, \quad A^2 -2aA + I = 0
$$

Is $ A \in \operatorname{SO}(2)\; $ if $A^n \in SO(2)\;$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$?

$\operatorname{SO}(2)$ is special orthogonal group.

Comment: Nope. You can find examples where $A^2 \in \text{SO}(2)$ but $A$ doesn't have determinant $1$.

Comment: What do you know (explicitly) about $SO(2)$ that you could use here?

Comment: $A$ must have determinant $1$ because $A^2 -2aA+ I =0 $condition

Comment: I don't understand why $A^2-2aA+I=0$ implies $\det A=1$. But  $A^2-2A+I=0$ does.

Comment: you may think Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. of course $tr A = 2a$ so $a=d$

Comment: @Shiyu If you write out all the equations involved, valchemist's equation implies that $a=d$ and $a^2-bc=1$ meaning that $\det A = 1$. I think the answer to valchemist's question is yes, but I'm still working out the math.

Comment: Michael// Thanks, I'm appreciating you, it is hard to find out norm condition

Comment: if we get $b+c =0 $, The problem will be solved

Comment: Can't we just use the argument that the orthogonal group is generated by reflections?

Comment: what is the $n$ in $A^n\in SO(2)$? $n=2,3,...$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised since nobody tried to find a counter-example! Let $p$ be a nonzero real number and
$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -p \\ p^{-1} & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then we have $A^2 - \sqrt{2}A + I = O$ and $A^4 = -I \in SO(2)$, but still $A \notin SO(2)$ unless $p = \pm 1$.

But this is partially true if some auxiliary conditions are imposed. For example, let's denote $a = \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is allowed to have complex value in the case $|a| > 1$. Also, let $n$ be the least positive integer satisfying $A^n \in SO(2)$. If we impose the condition that $\sin n\theta \neq 0$, then $A \in SO(2)$. (The condition $\sin n\theta \neq 0$ corresponds to the condition that $A^n \neq \pm I$.)

Let's prove this claim. Here we further assume that $a \neq \pm 1$, so that $\sin \theta \neq 0$. Later this excluded cases will be treated separately. Since
$$x^2 - 2ax + 1 = (x - e^{i\theta})(x - e^{-i\theta}),$$
we have
$$x^n = (x^2 - 2ax + 1)q_n (x) + \frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta} x - \frac{\sin (n-1)\theta}{\sin \theta}.$$
Now by assumption and the fact pointed out by Michael Banaszek, we can write
$$\frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta} A - \frac{\sin (n-1)\theta}{\sin \theta} I = A^n = R_{\varphi}, \ \cdots \ (1)$$
where
$$R_{\varphi} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi & -\sin\varphi \\ \sin\varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix}$$
is the rotation matrix corresponding to the angle $\varphi$. Now comparing the trace of both sides of (1), we find that
$$\sin n\theta \cos \theta - \sin(n-1)\theta = \sin \theta \cos \varphi,$$
or by addition formula for sine, we have
$$\cos\varphi = \cos n\theta.$$
In particular, $\theta$ is real and $\theta = \frac{1}{n}(\varphi + 2\pi k )$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Plugging this back to (1) and simplifying, we obtain
$$\quad A = R_{\theta}.$$
Here we critically used the fact that $\sin n\theta = \sin \varphi$ is nonzero.

Now we treat the case when $a = \pm 1$. In this case, we hvae
$$ x^n = (x^2 - 2ax + 1)q_n (x) + n a^{n-1} x - (n-1) a^{n} .$$
Then by assumption,
$$ n a^{n-1} A - (n-1) a^{n} I = A^n = R_{\varphi}$$
for some $\varphi$. Now take $k$-power to both sides to obtain
$$ kna^{kn-1}A - (kn-1)a^{kn}I = A^{kn} = R_{k\varphi}.$$
Dividing both sides by $kn a^{nk-1}$, we have
$$ A = a \left( 1 - \frac{1}{kn}\right)I + \frac{a^{1-nk}}{nk} R_{k\varphi}.$$
But since $a^{1-nk} R_{k\varphi}$ is uniformly bounded, taking $k \to \infty$ gives
$$ A = aI,$$
which is again in $SO(2)$.

Comment: Can you generalize your argument for the maximal compact subgroup in a real Lie group?

Comment: @Andrea Mori : Unfortunately, I'm almost completely ignorant at Lie group theory...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes I believe. Your requirement that $A^2-2aA+I=0$ forces $\det(A)=1$, so we know that if $A^n \in SO(2)$, then $\det(A^n)=\det(A)=1$, so we've eliminated the problem that Qiaochu mentioned. Now, it can be shown using a little bit of algebra that any matrix $B$ in $SO(2)$ is of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} \sin x & -\cos x \\ \cos x & \sin x \end{pmatrix}\ $$ Looking at a few powers of this matrix, we see that $$ B^2= \begin{pmatrix} -\cos 2x & -\sin 2x \\ \sin 2x & -\cos 2x \end{pmatrix}\ \text{and  } B^3= \begin{pmatrix} -\sin 3x & \cos 3x \\ -\cos 3x & -\sin 3x \end{pmatrix}\ $$ Thus, if we have $A^n \in SO(2)$, then if we finagle the signs and possibly switch $\sin $ and $\cos $ in a very natural way, it seems like $A$ will also be of the proper form with angle $\frac{x}{n}$, implying $A \in SO(2)$.

This isn't a rigorous proof, but I believe it at least gives the method of it.

**Edit:** As Shiyu pointed out, if $B$ is instead written in the form $$ \begin{pmatrix} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x \end{pmatrix}\ $$ then $$ B^k = \begin{pmatrix} \cos kx & -\sin kx \\ \sin kx & \cos kx \end{pmatrix}\ $$ so if $A^n \in SO(2)$ then $$ A^n = \begin{pmatrix} \cos y & -\sin y \\ \sin y & \cos y \end{pmatrix}\ \implies A= \begin{pmatrix} \cos \frac{y}{n} & -\sin \frac{y}{n} \\ \sin \frac{y}{n} & \cos \frac{y}{n} \end{pmatrix}\ $$ so $A \in SO(2)$

Comment: Thank your suggestion. Probably the perfect solution is to find out norm condition $a^2+b^2=1$ or $b+c=0$

Comment: A suggestion: if we write $B=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \cos x & -\sin x \\
    \sin x & \cos x \\
  \end{array}
\right)$
then we have
 $B^k=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \cos kx & -\sin kx \\
    \sin kx & \cos kx \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Hmm, That's just a possible case. We don't know why colume vector's norm of $A$ must $1$

Comment: You would have to show *every* possible nth root of $A^n$ has the form you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^n=I$ for $n=2,3,...$, I think the answer is yest.

$A\in SO(2)$ if and only if $\det A=1$ and $AA^T=I$.

Since $A^2(A^2)^T=I$ and $A^3(A^3)^T=I$, we have $A^3(A^3)^T=AA^2(A^2)^TA^T=AA^T=I$. In addition, as Michael Banaszek mentioned $\det A=1$, we conclude $A\in SO(2)$.

Comment: No, I don't mean $n=2,3\ldots$ $\quad$  $n$ is given some natural number

Comment: For Example, if $$A^9 = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & \sqrt{3}/2 \\ -\sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$$, $A \in SO(2)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is not necessarily. Because the orthogonal group is generated by reflections (and, for SO(n) , the largest order is n, i.e., if R is a rotation in SO(n), R is the composition of at-most n reflections). Take, then, a reflection Re with $Re^2=Ro$ , where $Ro$ is a rotation . Then $Re^{2n}=(Re^2)^n$ is a rotation, as a
composition of rotations, but Re itself is not a rotation.

A similar argument for reflections Re' with $Re^{2n+1}=Ro'$ shows that if $A^n$ is a rotation, it does not follow that A must be a rotation.